# How do you use JQuery onload function properly while using PHP include files?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, include

Basically, I have a header.php file located inside my INC folder. 
*header.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="EN">

        <head>

            <title> <?php echo $pageTitle; ?> </title>

            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

            <!--Boostrap's CDN-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

            <!--Custom CSS Styling-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/custom.css" type="text/css" />

        </head>

        <body onload="Slider();">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">

                <div class="container-fluid">

                    <div class="navbar-header">

                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"> Vomica </a>

                    </div>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                        <li class="<?php if($section == "home") {echo "active";} ?>"> <a href="index.php"> Home </a> </li>
                        <li class="<?php if($section == "buy") {echo "active";} ?>"> <a href="buy.php"> Buy </a> </li>
                        <li class="<?php if($section == "sell") {echo "active";} ?>"> <a href="sell.php"> Sell </a> </li>

                    </ul>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                        <li class="<?php if($section == "register") {echo "active";} ?>"> <a href="register.php"> Register </a> </li>
                        <li class="<?php if($section == "login") {echo "active";} ?>"> <a href="login.php"> Login </a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="logout.php"> Logout </a> </li>

                    </ul>

                </div>

            </nav>
```

As you can see I have a body for my header file meaning I can't call body inside another file. So, I want a function inside JQuery as soon as the body loads in.

How would I come about solving this?

I realize that I could just put this in the header but, it's extremely inefficient to call that function to every single page that doesn't need it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery to load specific page

```js
$( "#Body" ).load( "ajax/slider.html", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

where Body is id of body tag and slider is page that we want to load on body

Answer (score 0):

Slider may come only into the home page, not in the other pages. So you no need to call the Slider(); function into the body tag.

Use this code after `<nav>` tag or where would you like to add slider

```
<?php if($pageTitle=="home") { ?> //$pageTitle is some identifier to is this home page ;
  <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
        Slider(); 
      });
  </script>
<?php } ?>
```

You can use this way. It may help you.